# ¿Como cambiar el idioma de los errores c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy con un Proyecto en ASP.NET Core 3.0, no entiendo como cambiar el idioma de las respuestas de los errores.

> The value '' is invalid.

a

> El valor '' no es valido.

la idea es que se cambie para toda la solución, no solo para una vista o un modelo. sino que para todos use esa traducción.

Comment: Mira en esta pregunta en el [foro](https://forums.asp.net/t/1997875.aspx?Visual+Studio+Error+Message+in+other+language+except+english+) de Microsoft creo que la respuesta es la ultima pero echale un ojo a lo demas

Comment: Gracias! ya lo miro...

Comment: ya encontré la solución, agregue la respuesta a esta pregunta ;) Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontré la solución a mi problema.

en `Startup.cs`

modifique estas lineas:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMvcOptions(options => {
             options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 50;
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingBindRequiredValueAccessor((x) => "No se proporcionó un valor apra la propiedad '" + x + "'.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingKeyOrValueAccessor(() => "Se requiere un valor.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor((x) => "El valor '" + x + "' no es valido.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x,y) => "El valor '" + x + "' no es valido para " + y + ".");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "El valor proporcionado no es válido para '" + x + "'.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "El valor '" + x + "' no es valido.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor((x) => "El campo '" + x + "' debe ser un número.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingRequestBodyRequiredValueAccessor(() => "Se requiere un cuerpo de solicitud no vacío.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "El valor '" + x + "' no es valido.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor(() => "El valor proporcionado no es válido.");
             options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyValueMustBeANumberAccessor(() => "El campo debe ser un número.");        });
```

Gracias